# CSS/html auto adjusting line joining left-aligned word and right aligned

Tags: css, html

I have been trying to make a line join two words.
Sentence 1 would be on the left and no 2 on the right.everything should be on the same line.

I want the line to be flexible and adjust its width when the browser is re sized, and have so far failed miserably to do this.

It would be similar to this :

see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Puigcerber/vLwDf/1/)

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<h1>This is a longer heading</h1>
```

*CSS*

---

```
h1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
    background-color: #000;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}
h1:before {
    right: 0.5em;
    margin-left: -50%;
}
h1:after {
    left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: -50%;
}
```

but with only one line joining the words.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vLwDf/194/)

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
<div class="headerPart1">Heading</div>
<div class="headerPart2">This is a longer heading</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.headerPart1, .headerPart2 {
    display: inline-block; 
    clear: none;
}
```

Comment: If the `<h1>`'s have semantic value, why would you change them to divs? Your argument that they 'want to be separate' goes for `div`s as well, they're both block-level elements. Your fiddle works just the same with `h1`s: http://jsfiddle.net/vLwDf/195/

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for: Is this http://jsfiddle.net/gSsGy/1/

I've added a `width: 50%` to the h1 element and then floated it to left.

Answer (score 0):

Demo : [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/UwCVn/)

just add:

```
.header {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
h1{
    display: inline-block; 
    clear: none;
}
```

and this div before h1:

```
<div class="headercontent">
```